# Application not restarting after normal exit

Tags: elixir, erlang-supervisor, elixir-mix

I am trying to connect to mqtt using `tortoise`. When my connection drops it connects on the with no problem but when my application exits it is not getting restarted according to `:one_to_one` strategy. I started application in `mod` of mix.exs. Shall I put it in supervisor and start the supervisor? It demands for `start` with no arguments what is the right way to achieve this. What if my application crashes? 
And is my `connection.ex` must be genserver?
Please suggest.

**mix.exs**

```
defmodule SslMqtt.MixProject do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :ssl_mqtt,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.6",
      start_permanent: Mix.env() == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help compile.app" to learn about applications.
  def application do
    [
     mod: {SslMqtt.Application,[]}, 
     extra_applications: [:logger]
    ]
  end

  # Run "mix help deps" to learn about dependencies.
  defp deps do
    [
    {:tortoise, "~> 0.9"}
      # {:dep_from_hexpm, "~> 0.3.0"},
      # {:dep_from_git, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/my_dep.git", tag: "0.1.0"},
    ]
  end
end
```

**application.ex**

```
defmodule SslMqtt.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do

    IO.puts "inside supervisor application start"
    SslMqtt.Supervisor.start_link(name: SslMqtt.Supervisor)
  end
end
```

**supervisor.ex**

```
defmodule SslMqtt.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link(opts) do
    IO.puts "inside supervisor start link"
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, opts)
  end

  def init(:ok) do

    IO.puts "inside supervisor init"
    children = [

  %{
        id: SslMqtt.MqttConnection,
        start: { SslMqtt.MqttConnection, :start_link, [1,2]},
        type: :worker,
        restart: :permanent,
        shutdown: 500
      }

    ]

    Supervisor.init(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

**connection.ex**

```
defmodule SslMqtt.MqttConnection do

def start_link(_type,_arg) do

{:ok,pid}=Tortoise.Connection.start_link(
    client_id: William,
    server: {Tortoise.Transport.Tcp, host: 'iot.eclipse.org', port: 1883},
    handler: {Tortoise.Handler.Logger, []},
    will: %Tortoise.Package.Publish{topic: "foo/bar", payload: "goodbye"}
  )
end



end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your `Application`. It should be

```rb
def start(_type, _args) do
  children = [
    {SslMqtt.Supervisor, []}
  ]

  opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: SslMqtt.Supervisor]
  Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
end
```

That way the application would supervise `SslMqtt.Supervisor`. What you are doing now, you just start `SslMqtt.Supervisor`, unsupervised.

Comment: Yes I got it.. But will it handle if my application itself crashes?

Comment: Your application will be restarted by _ErlangVM_.